# VB.net Examples for Prism MVVM In Silverlight

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, mvvm, prism

Hey guys IM Looking at Implementing MVVM in Silverlight.  Kind of new to Silverlight and I'm Definately new to MVVM Pattern.

I get it all But I want A set of small Prism VB.Net MVVM exmaples if that makes sense.

Anyone have anything

Comment: If not examples of that where should I go to start learning C# all the examples for this are in C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use prism if you like. I prefer MEF and MVVM Light. The two together are like prism, but less overhead.

Comment: MEF?  Yea i just got MVVM Light whats a good tutorial on that bad boy

Comment: If you need a sample, email me at rickrat at gmail

Answer (score 0):

The microsoft examples are a great place to start.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16800